# Creating a matrix report and linking the rows to the columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have this query below that works quite well generating a report like this:

```
Jimmy |  Sword |  3
Jimmy |  Axe   |  0
Jimmy |  Bow   |  7
Alex  |  Sword |  1
Alex  |  Axe   |  11
Alex  |  Bow   |  0
Kate  |  Sword |  4
Kate  |  Axe   |  6
Kate  |  Bow   |  1
```

However, the powers-at-be want the PartName data across the top as columns, and then the worker and 'Total Made' count as rows for each part.

So it would look something like this:

```
    Sword   |   Axe   | Bow

Jimmy     3          0       7
Alex      1          11      0
Kate      4          6       1
```

Here is my fairly simple query that produces the first/original report:

```
SELECT
      WorkerName, PartName, 
      Count(PartName) AS 'Total Made' FROM Parts_List
WHERE userID IN (select userID from warehouse1)

GROUP BY PartName, WorkerName
```

I figured out how to get the PartName as columns by creating a matrix and then adding a Dataset with a query like this:

```
select PartName From Parts_List
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the rows of workers and their Count(PartName) to line up with the columns.

Does SSRS even support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the query you have it is possible get the required matrix using this data arragement:

Add a matrix to the report surface, in Column Group add `PartName` column and add `Worker Name` to Row Groups. To show Total made add it in the below `PartName` cell.

[image]

It will produce this:

[image]

Let me know if you need further help.